# Can Fs-Extra delete only files in a directory?

Tags: node.js, fs-extra

Can I do delete all files in apples directory without deleting the directory itself? [fs-extra API](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#removedir-callback) does not describe if it is possible.

```
 fsExtra.remove 'apples/*', ->
    if !err
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [emptyDir](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#emptydirdir-callback)

> Ensures that a directory is empty. If the directory does not exist, it is created. The directory itself is not deleted.

```
fsExtra.emptyDir 'apples/', ->
    if !err
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! Still it would be interesting to know if `.remove 'apples/*'` would work.